# HDLC Extended Addressing

Tags: c, encoding, protocols

Can any one please provide me with good resource information about where and how I can understand the encoding of the "Address field" (in an HDLC frame) into Octets, using the extended bit (bit 0), in the even of extending addressing.

Let us assume I want to send the address 0x1234, what will be the final octets after encoding with the extended bit. Hope you can understand my question?

Thanks in anticipation.

The address field range can be extended by reserving the first transmitted bit (low-order) of each address octet which would then be set to binary zero to indicate that the following octet is an extension of the address field. The format of the extended octet(s) shall be the same as that of the first octet. Thus, the address field may be recursively extended. The last octet of an address field is indicted by setting the low-order bit to binary one. See Fig 1 of attached. [image: Fig1]
When extension is used, the presence of a binary "1" in the first transmitted bit of the first address octet indicates that only one address octet is being used. The use of address extension thus restricts the range of single octet addresses to 0x7F and for two octet addresses to 0…0x3FFF.

Lower HDLC Address = 3FFF H = 0011111111111111 B

Upper HDLC Address = 1234 H = 0001001000110100 B

Considering the Address above and its encoded result shown in Fig 2, I really want to know how they got to this final encoded octet (fig 2) [image: Fig2]. 
I was unable to fix it up. That was why I needed more information that can help me understand. Can anyone please provide some simple Explanation? Thanks.

Comment: Like http://www.armware.dk/RFC/rfc/rfc3572.html and from there to http://www.armware.dk/RFC/rfc/rfc2175.html

Comment: @nos please read the edits above. I kind of explained my question further Thanks

Comment: @ott Please read the edits above. I kind of explained my question further Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I saw good decription here
http://www.interfacebus.com/HDLC_Protocol_Description.html

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2687

[http://www.cse.dmu.ac.uk/~cfi/Networks/DataLink/DataLink12.htm](http://www.cse.dmu.ac.uk/%7Ecfi/Networks/DataLink/DataLink12.htm)

Comment: Please read the edits above. I kind of explained my question further Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1111111b + 128 * 1111111b = 0x3FFF
0110100b + 128 * 0100100b = 0x1234

From here it's apparent that they took each of these hex numbers and extracted from them 7 least significant and 7 most significant bits (assuming there're only 14 in total) and just put them into 4 octets.

Comment: I do not understand please. Please can you explain using the extended bit encoding rule as illustrated in the edit above. This will help me understand you much more better. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to group it different where u is the unicast bit x is the LSB:

```
u1 0010 0x 011 0100x 11 1111 1x 111 1111x
 1    2      3    4   3    F      F    F
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer in Simple steps.

1. Split the 2 bytes into 2 half's (Upper half & Lower half)of 8 bits each
2. Eliminate the 2 MSB of the upper half
3. The resultant is a 14 bit, which you split into 2 half's of 7 bits each.
4. Add the extension bit to the LSB of each half, hence the resultant of  8 bit each.
5. The result gives the Encoded Octet!

Note that step 1 could be avoided, but I just wanted to help simplify the answer. Thanks to all who contributed, and I do hope this helps someday!